# err_name_not_resolved issue after switching hosting service

Tags: database, wordpress, ssl, dns, cloudways

Interesting issue I've run into when switching from Digital Ocean to Cloudways Digital Ocean plan. The styling and images do not load on the site with error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED." If it's any use, I switched my domain from uncvrd.co to www.uncvrd.co and added a Let's Encrypt SSL. Here are the errors I see in the Chrome Console:

[image]

It appears that it is trying to load resources but something about the URL prevents the page from properly loading the content. Please let me know if you need any more info and I will happily provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have check your screenshot Its not hosting change issue.Its path related issue.You are added space at end of url its converted in `%20%`.while browser load resource it convert 'www.example.co ' to 'www.example.co%20%'.

**How to solve**

**Case 1:** Goto your wp-admin and Select general setting remove space of site url and home url.update paramlinks from setting.

**Case 2:** In case above is not working,Login to database and goto wp_option file option name site_url and home_url update those two url.

That's it.I hop this will helpful.

Comment: funnily enough, I added an "s" to http in general settings and it worked on my computer. HOWEVER, if I check on mobile device I still see the same "unstyled" layout, is this just a propagation issue that should be resolved within the next few hours? I found out I can log onto admin on another computer, click "visit site" at the top left and the styles/icons will load properly...interesting. Thoughts?